# Compressing Images on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, image-compression

I want to compress images on pre-compilation. What gem can I use for this?

My image sizes are pretty big as per google pagespeed and can be reduced by 90%.

Comment: If I may ask, must it be on pre compile? Why not optimize the base image itself or create lesser quality versions instead? If the previous is fine I can definitely go down the path of using boht lossless and lossy compression to optimize.

Comment: Because I already have images on my server. I will have to download, compress and then upload again.

Answer (score 0):

[image_optim gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/image_optim) looks like a good candidate. It's under [active development](https://github.com/toy/image_optim). I'm going to try it out.